# App on android studio doesn't load properly

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been programming an app for Android Studio, however for some reason the app stopped loading properly suddenly, what I mean by that is the App loads up and all you can see is the Blue bar on top (without the app title) and blank white space below (and it shouldn't be blank).

so here are some things I tried:

- load an earlier version of the project that worked fine for sure(although even the current did).
- try to debug through an actual android phone.
- clean and rebuild.
- Reinstalled Android studio fresh with default settings.
- reboot PC.
- Waiting for very long.
- smashing my head into the wall with an exponentially increasing force.

Any help is extremely appreciated.

btw I'm using Windows 10 - 64 bit.

[![appearentely the blue title bar was just in my imagination][1]][1]

found the problem in the code thanks for all the help
for those wondering I basically made an infinite loop accidentialy in the method getDays without realizing.

Comment: Post your manifest,activity code and xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know every time when you override a method, you must reference super. Before setcontentView call super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: actually I do, I just removed it to check some things, then I readded it, it isn't the problem.

Comment: I just used your code and works fine on my device. I removed the Holiday features that class not provided. Gently clean your project and try to run on another avm, ıt would be better if you create a fresh project and do it too. That white screen means your layout not at all loaded. If you did not give any theme, at least you should see Toolbar or ActıonBar same stuff. I am not sure but you may need to check your AVM's image might failed. But I am pretty sure that you should not even be able to run without calling super. If you dont want to create fresh app, create ferssh activity and launch it

Comment: I checked it out and the problem is most certainly in the code, since an older version of the app (2 days ago before I added a lot of stuff). 
seems to show the layout well.
what did you change exactly in order for it to work for you?

Comment: Please start fresh project and run it. If you see works ok, try adding slowly to catch something. The same code whıch I am able to work

Comment: thank you very much! I figured the problem as posted above.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually adding stuff to the activity's layout then try clean and build.

Comment: I didn't touch the layout before it stopped working, but I try already to clean and build, forgot to mention it.

Comment: manifest content, java content and your layouts' content.  Also stacktrace from log.

Comment: I added what you asked.